# Background image with link

Tags: html, css

[backgroundimage with link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcGgh.png)

I'm trying to add a link to the image I attached but I can't figure it out, I'm a beginner and I need help :))

This is what I have done so far:

```css
a {
  margin-left: -.625rem;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/55hHtt5/super-promotii.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
```

Comment: You cannot add links to background images. This is CSS not HTML or JavaScript. CSS can't populate HTML links.

Comment: why not adding an anchor and setting it's background to the image you want?

Comment: I've added a code snippet to your question. Your code works technically, but I assume the result is not desired. I suggest just using an `<img src="">` tag instead inside your anchor (`.navbar-nav`)

Answer (score 0):

You wrap the link around the element you are referencing. It might be a nav instead of div but:

```
<a href='yourLinkURL'><div class='navbar-nav'></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.. you should add width and height for background image

**css**

```
.header-menu > .navbar-nav {
        background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/55hHtt5/super-promotii.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
height: 58px;
width: 250px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="navbar-nav" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcGgh.png">
</div>
```

You can change div to anchor tag & link with href

```
<a class="navbar-nav" href="https://www.google.com">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcGgh.png">
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

In css, you cannot include `href` link for image displayed through `background-image` property.
`href` can be handled only in HTML

Comment: You can indeed link external images in the `background-image` property.

Comment: you have wrongly understood. external image path can be ofcourse included in the background-image: url() property. but the question is about implementing a href link which would make the user to redirect to specific webpage when user clicks on the background image